# Remove a DOM element when the app goes to the background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove an iframe from the DOM when the user leaves my Ionic app so the YouTube video stops playing.

I am using the `pause` and `resume` events:

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('onResume');
});

$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function() {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('onPause');
});
```

The `pause` event is triggered when I leave the app and the `resume` event is triggered when I open it again (I checked the time to make sure they were not both triggered on `resume`) but the iframe is not removed from the DOM.

I use `ng-if="showVideo"` on the `div` wrapping the iframe and `$scope.showVideo = false;` to remove it:

```
$scope.$on('onPause', function () {
  $scope.showVideo = false;
  alert(Date.now() / 1000);
});
```

It works perfectly when I switch pages using the `beforeLeave` event:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
  $scope.showVideo = false;
});
```

Is there some kind of limitation on what Ionic can do when the app is in the background? Are there other ways to stop a video when the user leaves the app?

Comment: Is it capture onblur event to do the job?

Comment: @TheKNVB The `pause` event is triggered but only some actions are performed (an `alert()` works but the `$scope.showVideo = false;` doesn't remove the iframe from the DOM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the YouTube iframe API:

```
$scope.$on('onPause', function () {
  $('iframe').each(function () {
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')
  });
});
```

It turns out that we can't modify the DOM when the app is in background mode but we can communicate with the iframe.